# createControl for TinyMCE 4.0

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have read doc API 4.0 but nothing how to use createControl because current code is not work with tinymce 4.0.

API version 3.0
[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Plugin.createControl](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Plugin.createControl)

so, how to use it for tinymce 4.0 ?

Thanks

Comment: might be this is what you want http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13246/how-i-can-i-add-a-split-button-or-list-box-to-the-wordpress-tinymce-instance

Comment: Its true, tinyMCE 4.0 has removed this, it still has a controlManager object but literally no current documentation. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: hi jogesh_pi, your link is old topic.
hi Evan, check my answer below. it's solving my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, thank you

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.name', {
  init : function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('button', {
      title: '',
      onclick: function() {}
    }
  }

});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('name', tinymce.plugins.name);
```